# PHP Optional String Part

Tags: php

I have to check if a $url equals to a string with an optional part:

```
if ($url === 'http://www.example.com/login/') {}
```

Where the trailing slash "/" at the end of "login" is optional.

How to make it return TRUE with or without the trailing slash?

Comment: I know this but I remember I came across an example looking like a regex without using OR.

Comment: `strpos` is what you looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [rtrim()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.rtrim.php) function in this case :

```
if (rtrim($url, '/') === 'http://www.example.com/login') {
}
```

**[Demo without trailing slash](http://codepad.org/ic3baMwt)**
**[Demo with trailing slash](http://codepad.org/bX0rQAVf)**

Comment: Wouldn't this also trim the slashes after http and after .com etc?

What he could do is also rtrim the $url

Comment: Take a second look at that

Comment: Yeah thanks, I forgot to remove the trailing slash in the test case the first time.

Comment: @Brewal I'm sorry, I had a small brain failure. Entschuldigung.

Comment: you should be the one to take a second look at what you've just done

Answer (score 3):

try using the stripos function:

```
if(stripos($url,'http://www.example.com/login') !== false){}
```

Note: used stripos (case insensitive strpos() ) in case the URL is spelled with uppercase letters

Comment: Remove the trailing slash from your string if you want it to be optional. Btw, any other URL containing `http://www.example.com/login` would also match.

Comment: I was not payiing attention to that trailing ' / ' :) I edited it :)

Answer (score 2):

User regular expression:

```
if(preg_match("@http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/login\/?)$@") == 1)
```

Comment: Good solution but you dont need the `== 1` part

Comment: You don't necessarily need it to work as expected, but it's still OK to check for return value isn't it.

Comment: in a boolean condition, `1` will always evaluate to `true` and `0` to `false`. If it returns an error, it returns `false` too, so if you don't want to know if it didn't work or if it didn't work because of an error, then no, `== 1` is very not necessary at all, and yes, just avoiding it IS checking the (casted to boolean) return value. If you really want to use it, then I would prefer `=== 1`

Comment: @Capsule I second everything you said, but I want to add that in our company we have a policy of explicitly writing checks after library functions for the purpose of instantly understanding what check is performed. It's a question of clean-code. While it creates a tiny overhead by adding a check to the function in question, it is much more readable, and processor time for a simple check is nothing that needs micro optimization. The time a coworker needs to understand functions he doesn't know can rather be spent implementing time-consuming tasks like big database queries

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($url === 'http://www.example.com/login/' || $url === 'http://www.example.com/login') {}
```

|| means Or so if $url is equal to http://www.example.com/login/ OR $url is equal to http://www.example.com/login

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php